# How to create mutiple instance of ssh and how to add specific users to specific instances?

Tags: sftp

I want to open multiple ports for ssh server and want to add some users to specific port only.How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, reread `man  sshd` and `man sshd_config`.

Then, re-think your desire - is this the best/easiest way to do it? It looks like a Hard Way to me.

Then, create multiple versions of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, (e.g. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.Port22`, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.Fred`, ...) each differing at least in

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
```

the `port number`. Make any other changes to each version of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that you want to.

Then, look at `/etc/init.d/ssh` and `/etc/init/ssh.conf` (which is how `sshd` gets started), modify them to start multiple `sshd`s, using the `-f <configfile>` switch to select different configurations.